# In Bash, what is the difference between a scalar and single-element array?

Tags: arrays, bash

Except for the difference in how the are reported by `declare -p`, is a scalar indistinguishable from a single-element array?  Is it safe to treat them as equivalent?

```
X="cat"   # scalar
Y=("cat") # single-element array
```

In general, if you if you use an array in an expression as if it were a scalar, you get the first array element.  Furthermore, if you use a scalar as an array, it acts like a single-element array.

`declare -p` shows that they are distinct.  (I show command output in comments.)

```
declare -p X Y # declare -- X="cat" 
               # declare -a Y=([0]="cat")
```

If you treat the array as a scalar, it acts like a scalar.

```
echo string length: ${#X} ${#Y}                   # string length: 3 3
echo values: $X $Y                                # values: cat cat
[ "$X" == "$Y" ] && echo "equality test is true"  # equality test is true
```

If you treat the scalar like an array, it acts a single-element array.

```
echo "array length:   ${#X[@]} ${#Y[@]}"  # array length:   1 1
echo "array indexing: ${X[0]}  ${Y[0]}"   # array indexing: cat cat 
echo \"${X[1]}\" \"${Y[1]}\"              #                 ""  ""
```

Responses from "M. Nejat Aydin" and "Ed Morton" show that they are not always equivalent.  Thanks.

Comment: In some parameter expansions, they are not equivalent. For instance, `${X[@]:0:1}` and `${Y[@]:0:1}` expand differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ X="cat"   # scalar
$ Y=("cat") # single-element array
```

```
$ echo "${X[@]:1}"
at
$ echo "${Y[@]:1}"
$
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.  For the sake of other readers, here's some explanation.

Comment: ${X[@]:1} is "at"; the string "cat" from index t to the end.
${Y[@]:1} is the array from element 1 to the end.  If Y had more elements, it would look like this:   `Y=(1 2 3 4 5); echo "${Y[@]:1}" # 2 3 4 5`

Answer (score 3):

According to `man bash`:

> An  *indexed array* is created automatically if any variable is assigned to using the syntax `name[subscript]=value`.
> ...
>
> Referencing an array <sup>(either *indexed array* or *associative array*)</sup> variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing the array with a subscript  of `0`.

Comment: The two cases are equivalent for most usage (e.g. echo $X $Y), but there are differences, as pointed out by "M. Nejat Aydin" and "Ed Morton".  @pynexj's explanation here is helpful, but their answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [bash sourcecode](https://github.com/gitGNU/gnu_bash/blob/bc007799f0e1362100375bb95d952d28de4c62fb/arrayfunc.c#LL201C1-L209C46):

```c
/* Perform an array assignment name[ind]=value.  If NAME already exists and
   is not an array, and IND is 0, perform name=value instead.  If NAME exists
   and is not an array, and IND is not 0, convert it into an array with the
   existing value as name[0].

   If NAME does not exist, just create an array variable, no matter what
   IND's value may be. */
SHELL_VAR *
bind_array_variable (name, ind, value, flags)
```